# Proving if $g(n)=\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}5n-1&n\text{ is odd}\\n/4\ &\ n\text{ is even}\end{smallmatrix}\right.$ is primitive recursive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, computability

Is $g$ primitive recursive and if so, prove it, where
$$g(n) = \begin{cases} 5n - 1 & n \text{ is odd} \\
 \lfloor n/4 \rfloor & n \text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

I have access to the predecessor, multiplication functions and bounded minimisation (don't need to prove that they're primitive recursive).

When $n$ is odd, $g(n) = Pred(m(5,n))$, where Pred is the predecessor function and $m$ is the multiplication function.
When $n$ is even, $g(n) = max_{m \le n} : m(4,m)  \le n $

I'm not sure how to properly define this with a dummy variable or if my definition is primitive recursive for when $n$ is even, so any help there would be appreciated. I'm also not sure how to define $g(n+1)$ from $g(n)$ (this is how I've defined primitive recursion before).

Comment: It's not even a map from ${\mathbb N}$ to ${\mathbb N}$. Shouldn't the condition be $n$ divisible by $4$?

Comment: The way to prove this is not to express $g(n+1)$ in terms of $g(n)$, but by proving that the composition of primitive recursive functions is primitive recursive again, and writing $g$ as such a composition. As a basis, you're using functions such as $m, n \mapsto mn$ and $m, n \mapsto \lfloor m/n \rfloor$ which you _do_ prove to be primitive recursive directly using the definition. Of course, what it is that you actually have to prove, depends on what you can assume to be known, which is why it is so important to add context to a question.

Comment: yes I forgot to put that it is the floor (n/4), not just divides by